# How to change the format of a date in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date, date-formatting

I have a `date` formatted as `2018-06-13T13:28:14+0000`, and I want to change it into this format `13/6/2018 1:28:14 PM`.

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Thanks, in advance :)

Comment: Give a look here : https://momentjs.com/ - very powerful for date/time

Comment: HI! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. Every single possible "how do I parse/format this date" question has been asked and answered. But in the unlikely event you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your date `2018-06-13T13:28:14+0000` is in UTC format.

One of the simplest options is to use **[momentjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-formats/)** to get desired date time format.

```
moment(yourDate).utc().format("DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss a")
```

Below is code:

```js
let date = moment("2018-06-13T13:28:14+0000").utc().format("DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss a")

console.log(date)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

the `toLocaleString()` function with the `en-US`locale is close to what you are searching for. Would this be enough for you ? It will give you back something like :

```
today.toLocaleString("en-US");
// will give you => 6/15/2018, 9:03:58 AM
```

If you really need no comma, then use the `toLocaleString()` and then remove the comma like :

```
today.toLocaleString("en-US").replace(',','');
```

see : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Date/toLocaleString

Answer (score 2):

To format a `Date` in javascript you can use **[`Date.toLocaleDateString()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)**, it will give you many options to format dates.

This is a sample code snippet, you could use:

```js
var d = new Date();
var options = {
  year: 'numeric',
  month: 'numeric',
  day: 'numeric',
  hour: 'numeric',
  minute: 'numeric',
  second: 'numeric',
  hour12: true
};

console.log(d.toLocaleDateString('fr-FR', options));
```

**Note:**

Of course , you can play with options to get more possible results, you can check that in the Docs as well.

Otherwise, as suggested, you can use a JS library like **[Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)** or **[date-format](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format)**, they have better enhanced features.

Comment: Yes agree. momentjs has just one line of code for this and it will by default show time in your local format. Check my answer please.]

Comment: @VicJordan Yes, nice approach using momentjs as well, it's shorter and cleaner, but it's useful to show a ntaive JS option for doing things, as OP doesn't have momentjs tag.